# Create the sequence 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 with seq()

Tags: r

I'm trying to create the sequence `0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4` with the command `seq()`. Could anyone be able to tell me if it is possible to do such thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, by wrapping `seq()` inside a call to `rep()` using its `each` argument:

```
> rep(seq(0,4), each=5)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
>
```

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of not answering the question as posed, you don't need seq() for this. rep() will do the job.

```
> rep(0:4, each=5)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
>
```

Comment: That is functionally identical to what I posted eight minutes before you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *should* use the `rep` function, but here is a solution that uses `seq`:

```
floor(  seq(from=0, to=4+0.999, length.out=5*(4+1))  )
#### [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

And he command `floor` that rounds the numbers to the lowest integer.

Comment: But... it doesn't *only* use `seq`.